# Minecraft 1.8 - Iron golem farm questions on spawn rate and efficiency

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I've been building [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dev3Ls8papM) thing, to see how it works and if I can increase the efficiency some:

Now, I tried to increase the number of floors, but it's hard to determine the effects of it. Some times it seems as though the whole thing is broke as well.

[image: Eleveted farm]
[image: Elevated farm other side]

I have one pouch of villagers on either side, dont't know if that affects anything though.

**So my questions to this design is:**

Is this thing considered as one, larger village? Or two separate ones?
How far away (vertically) does the next layer need to be for it to be recognized as two separate villages?

Here is the other one, which I have extended the length of:
[image: Vertically extended]
[image: Vretically extended other side]

**And my questions to *this* design is:**

Does increasing the space, doors and villagers increase the chance of iron golems spawning? Or does it just increase the cap?

Comment: Given [this link](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming), the best way to spawn golem quickly is making different villages.  I'm not sure about the limit of golems in one single village, but it isn't great compared to detached villages.

Comment: Yeah, but how far away each other do they need to be, vertically, for them to be separate villages? I can't find this info anywhere

Comment: The center of the villages must be exactly 66 blocks apart. [Source](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Village#Advanced_Village_Placement).

Comment: Ah nice! :) That goes for all the axis'es then I reckon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Does adding more villagers, doors, or space increase the spawn rate?**

No. From the [Minecraft wiki on Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem#Spawning):

> The chance of spawning is 1 in 7000 per game tick

Adding more villagers, doors, or space does not change this fact. If you want more golems, you need more villages.

**How close can I place my villages?**

Again, [from the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village#Advanced_Village_Placement):

> If their centers are to share the same x & y or y & z coordinate then the remaining coordinate must differ by 66 or more.

**How do I determine where the center is?**

> Upon creation, a village center is defined as the [geometric barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of the active doors' locations

In summary, the most efficient design is to create a cluster of villages whose centers are spaced exactly 66 blocks apart (on any single axis). Each village must have at least 10 or more villagers.

You can extract tips and tricks from many tried and true designs [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming).

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding of villages goes there are three factors with your design that my impact on your design.

1. Villages are measured in doors. With the mean centre being the mid point for golem spawning which happens in any empty space within the given radius. Thus with your design it would be my expectation that some of the iron golems *might* spawn under the structure (again not 100% clear on this as working from memory here). Even so the spawn rate is never massively fast and needs a leave it and come back approach.
2. Farms would normally need to be 64 blocks apart - so 64 blocks straight up in your design. However if the centres share the same vertical coordinates then they need to be 66 blocks apart according tot he wiki.
3. Other designs that have seen that place the villagers on the outside place them on all four sides. This would seem to be to force the spawns to happen between them. If you are up for a little experimentation you might find you get different results.

Your question about doors: Doors do not increase the spawn rate but do increase the village cap. (see quote below).

> Golems will spawn in a 16×16×6 area, centered between the 21 or more
> valid doors in a village if it has at least 10 villagers. The chance
> of spawning is 1 in 7000 per game tick, which averages around one
> every six minutes. Iron golems can spawn provided the blocks it spawns
> in are transparent and the block it spawns on top of has a solid
> surface. --https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem

You probably know that you can see other people's designs here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Iron_golem_farming

Comment: This is a good answer :)
What about the second design I did? Does that increase the golem spawn rate? It does seem to be working faster, but that could very well be placebo effect on my part.

Comment: I would not have expected the spawn rate to change unless the second floor effectively doubled the village size which *might* improve the rate. The same boost could be gained by doubling doors and villagers if there was one.

Comment: Well, the second design does increase both doors and villagers. Since it's 10x20, it's 60 doors instead of 40 from the original design. And thus, more space for the golems to spawn on.

Comment: The spawn rate is either 0 per tick or 1/7000 per tick. You either qualify for spawning or you don't. It's an on off switch, not a rate that you can influence.